# .Net web api self hosting

Tags: c#, .net, https, asp.net-web-api, self-hosting

I developed a console application that is stored as a web service. 
In this console, I host a self-hosted web app service. Also, I open a thread that opens a web socket with another program (HTTP, port 443).... Now, when I initialize the web service, I can reach the self-hosted service, and the web socket works well. Now after 2-3 hours the web socket is closed and this is the exception that i get:

> "An established connection was aborted by the software in your host
>   machine".

Also, I get the following error:

> "Exception: Error message: Socket not connected"

..

Has anyone an idea for this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried turning your firewall off just to make sure? Also make sure that [HttpWebRequest.KeepAlive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.keepalive%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is turned on